# Printing min and max using a EOF loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, max, min

I am having difficulty writing a C program that reads real numbers from standard output and determines whether the number is max or min compared to all other numbers that were read previously. The program should read another real number until EOF occurs. Below is my attempt at the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double maximum = 0, minimum = 0, number;
    while (number != EOF) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%lf", &number);
        printf("%d", EOF);
        if (number > maximum) {
            maximum = number;
        }
        else if (number < minimum) {
            minimum = number;
        }
    }
    printf("\n Max number is: %lf", maximum);
    printf("Min number is: %lf", minimum);
    return 0;
}
```

The challenge is that I'm not allowed to use arrays.

Comment: Please pay attention. You cannot read from standard output.

Comment: Suggest "reads real numbers from standard output" --> "reads real numbers from standard input"

Comment: How does this not work?  Does it fail to compile?  Does it give the wrong answer?  Have you tried looking at it in the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. `number` is not initialized before the first iteration.
2. `scanf` expects the argument be a pointer, you pass in the *value*.
3. Also, I don't think the minimum is 0 (what about negatives?), and the
   maximum shouldn't be 0.
4. What if all the numbers are the same? you'd
   not get the right min

There are many ways to check for the end of input, I chose to use explicitly `feof`

Try something like this code:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double maximum = -DBL_MAX, minimum = DBL_MAX, number;
    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%lf", &number);
        if (number > maximum) {
            maximum = number;
        }
        if (number < minimum) {
            minimum = number;
        }
    }
    printf("\n Max number is: %lf", maximum);
    printf("Min number is: %lf", minimum);
    return 0;
}
```

Still, you need to improve error management.

Comment: for STDIN which library do i need to include?

Comment: `maximum = DBL_MIN` --> `maximum = -DBL_MAX`.  `DBL_MIN` is the smallest magnitude number > 0.  Not the least `double`.

Comment: My very rusty C, thanks @chux.  Changed the code to reflect your comment

Comment: Note: Better to use the return value of `scanf()` than `feof()`.  If user enters `"x"`, this code will go into an infinite loop.